# Why do I have to call overridden to_s method explicitly and not implicitly as I would expect with puts

Tags: ruby, overriding, irb

Here's the irb session where I have overridden the `to_s` of String class but had to call `to_s` explicitly:

```
➜ irb
2.2.0 :001 > class String
2.2.0 :002?>   def to_s
2.2.0 :003?>     swapcase
2.2.0 :004?>     end
2.2.0 :005?>   end
 => :to_s
2.2.0 :006 > puts 'hello'
hello
 => nil
2.2.0 :007 > p 'hello'
"hello"
 => "hello"
2.2.0 :008 > puts 'hello'.to_s
HELLO
 => nil
```

Comment: ➜ irb
2.2.0 :001 > class String
2.2.0 :002?>   def to_s
2.2.0 :003?>     swapcase
2.2.0 :004?>     end
2.2.0 :005?>   end
 => :to_s
2.2.0 :006 > puts 'hello'
hello
 => nil
2.2.0 :007 > p 'hello'
"hello"
 => "hello"
2.2.0 :008 > puts 'hello'.to_s
HELLO
 => nil

Comment: stack overflow can format your code nicely - use that (hit the edit button on your post) rather than using comments or linking to external sites.

Comment: Thanks.. m a newbie both at Ruby and stack overflow.
Will be heedful of that in my future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because `puts` only calls `to_s` on things which are not already strings. In your case `'hello`' is already a string, so `puts` doesn't need to call `to_s` on it (`puts` also contains explicit implementations for some other classes, such as arrays)

If on the other hand you had defined a `to_s` method on something that is not already a String then your to_s method should be called

```
class Foo
  def to_s
    'hello world'
  end
end
puts Foo.new
```

will output 'hello world'.

Comment: Yep..
just saw the implementation of to_s.
As you said, it checks if class is string.